# how to export datagridview into excel

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

How do I fix the error `System.InvalidCastException`? I don't find the solution, if I change the code with another code but the errors still same `System.InvalidCastException`:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "RekapPerangkatZTE";

for (int i = 1; i < dgvperangkat.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[i, 1] = dgvperangkat.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dgvperangkat.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dgvperangkat.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvperangkat.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();   
    }
}

var saveFileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialoge.FileName = "output";
saveFileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
if (saveFileDialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
app.Quit();
```

Comment: I can not see "where" you would get a `System.InvalidCastException` in the posted code. Are you sure the posted code throws this error and if so on which line? Other than the “misplaced” column index in the loop for setting the column headers… which should be… `worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dgvperangkat.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;` …. The code appears to work as expected. I am betting this error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: at line : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Excel library in the project? If not… right click on the “References” in the Solution Explorer and select “Add Reference”, A window will open, click on “COM” on the left side of the window, then scroll down and select “Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library”. The 16.0 is the version of Excel on your computer and may be different than 16.0. This assumes you have Excel installed on your computer. If you don’t, then you need to use the EPPlus Library or another third party Excel library.

Comment: yup, i already did that, but if i add 'Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library' another error came out with the error is :
Warning 1 Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel1". Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)) Telkom

Comment: Well it would appear you have found the problem. What version shows up in the “COM” window when you add the reference? Whatever version it is… that is the one you need to use. I recommend researching how to get the proper reference to the local Excel library. As I stated previously, the posted code works successfully in my tests.

Comment: so the problem is my computer ( i mean my microsoft office and my visual studios ) like that ? not the code ? so the solution is update my software ?

Comment: If you have MS Office properly installed on your computer, then a library SHOULD be there and you SHOULD be able to access this library by adding a reference as previously described. If you specify a library that is “different” from the one on your computer, then you will get the errors you describe. Therefore, IF you have office installed on your computer, then you are not setting the reference properly. Also make sure and REMOVE any references in the project that are not working, don’t just simply add another.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) . Fistly add your solution a helper class, that's name can be helper.cs, add static method ExportToExcel method. if you want to use in another code block, only you can call this methods.

System.InvalidCastException may be can be caused your data. I sent detailed code for your solutions, only call ExportToExcel method with datatable, directory info and file name, i hope it will be fix your problem. Dont forget adding EPPlus library on references. It's works all datatables, that is flexable all data.

[image: EPPlus References]
[image: EPPlus using lines]

```
//Usage example code
  DataTable table = new DataTable(); //Get or set your data to DataTable
  table = db.SampleResult.ToDataTable(); // This is sample, your data result can be here and it's must be datatable
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/ExportedFiles"));
  string fileName = "Sample_List;
  Helpers.ExportToExcel(table, di, fileName);
```

-Helper.cs

```
//Usings
using System.IO;
using OfficeOpenXml;
Using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
```

---

```
public static string ExportToExcel(DataTable dt, DirectoryInfo outputDir, string fileName)
    {
        FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\" + fileName + ".xlsx");
        string ReportName = "Sample Report";
        // If any file exists in this directory having name 'Sample1.xlsx', then delete it
        if (newFile.Exists)
        {
            //If you want to delete OR rename
            //newFile.Delete(); // ensures we create a new workbook
            //Random rnd = new Random();
            //string random = rnd.Next(100, 999).ToString();
            //newFile = new FileInfo(outputDir.FullName + @"\" + fileName + random + ".xlsx");
        }
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
        {
            // Add a worksheet to the empty workbook
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(ReportName);
            worksheet.Row(1).Height = 20;


            int columnCount = dt.Columns.Count;


            // Add the headers
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, columnCount].Merge = true;
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = fileName + " Sample List Title - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Size = 15;
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;

            int intColumn = 1;

            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[2, intColumn].Value = column.ColumnName;

            string[] alphabet = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AF", "AG", "AH", "AI", "AJ", "AK", "AL", "AM", "AN", "AO", "AP", "AQ", "AR", "AS", "AT", "AU", "AV", "AW", "AX", "AY", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BC", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BK", "BL", "BM", "BN", "BO", "BP", "BQ", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BU", "BV", "BW", "BX", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CB", "CC", "CD", "CE", "CF", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CJ", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CP", "CQ", "CR", "CS", "CT", "CU", "CV", "CW", "CX", "CY", "CZ", "DA", "DB", "DC", "DD", "DE", "DF", "DG", "DH", "DI", "DJ", "DK", "DL", "DM", "DN", "DO", "DP", "DQ", "DR", "DS", "DT", "DU", "DV", "DW", "DX", "DY", "DZ", "EA", "EB", "EC", "ED", "EE", "EF", "EG", "EH", "EI", "EJ", "EK", "EL", "EM", "EN", "EO", "EP", "EQ", "ER", "ES", "ET", "EU", "EV", "EW", "EX", "EY", "EZ", "FA", "FB", "FC", "FD", "FE", "FF", "FG", "FH", "FI", "FJ", "FK", "FL", "FM", "FN", "FO", "FP", "FQ", "FR", "FS", "FT", "FU", "FV", "FW", "FX", "FY", "FZ", "GA", "GB", "GC", "GD", "GE", "GF", "GG", "GH", "GI", "GJ", "GK", "GL", "GM", "GN", "GO", "GP", "GQ", "GR", "GS", "GT", "GU", "GV", "GW", "GX", "GY", "GZ", "HA", "HB", "HC", "HD", "HE", "HF", "HG", "HH", "HI", "HJ", "HK", "HL", "HM", "HN", "HO", "HP", "HQ", "HR", "HS", "HT", "HU", "HV", "HW", "HX", "HY", "HZ", "IA", "IB", "IC", "ID", "IE", "IF", "IG", "IH", "II", "IJ", "IK", "IL", "IM", "IN", "IO", "IP", "IQ", "IR", "IS", "IT", "IU", "IV", "IW", "IX", "IY", "IZ", "JA", "JB", "JC", "JD", "JE", "JF", "JG", "JH", "JI", "JJ", "JK", "JL", "JM", "JN", "JO", "JP", "JQ", "JR", "JS", "JT", "JU", "JV", "JW", "JX", "JY", "JZ", "KA", "KB", "KC", "KD", "KE", "KF", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KJ", "KK", "KL", "KM", "KN", "KO", "KP", "KQ", "KR", "KS", "KT", "KU", "KV", "KW", "KX", "KY", "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LD", "LE", "LF", "LG", "LH", "LI", "LJ", "LK", "LL", "LM", "LN", "LO", "LP", "LQ", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LW", "LX", "LY", "LZ", "MA", "MB", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MF", "MG", "MH", "MI", "MJ", "MK", "ML", "MM", "MN", "MO", "MP", "MQ", "MR", "MS", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NB", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NF", "NG", "NH", "NI", "NJ", "NK", "NL", "NM", "NN", "NO", "NP", "NQ", "NR", "NS", "NT", "NU", "NV", "NW", "NX", "NY", "NZ", "OA", "OB", "OC", "OD", "OE", "OF", "OG", "OH", "OI", "OJ", "OK", "OL", "OM", "ON", "OO", "OP", "OQ", "OR", "OS", "OT", "OU", "OV", "OW", "OX", "OY", "OZ", "PA", "PB", "PC", "PD", "PE", "PF", "PG", "PH", "PI", "PJ", "PK", "PL", "PM", "PN", "PO", "PP", "PQ", "PR", "PS", "PT", "PU", "PV", "PW", "PX", "PY", "PZ", "QA", "QB", "QC", "QD", "QE", "QF", "QG", "QH", "QI", "QJ", "QK", "QL", "QM", "QN", "QO", "QP", "QQ", "QR", "QS", "QT", "QU", "QV", "QW", "QX", "QY", "QZ", "RA", "RB", "RC", "RD", "RE", "RF", "RG", "RH", "RI", "RJ", "RK", "RL", "RM", "RN", "RO", "RP", "RQ", "RR", "RS", "RT", "RU", "RV", "RW", "RX", "RY", "RZ", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "SE", "SF", "SG", "SH", "SI", "SJ", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SO", "SP", "SQ", "SR", "SS", "ST", "SU", "SV", "SW", "SX", "SY", "SZ", "TA", "TB", "TC", "TD", "TE", "TF", "TG", "TH", "TI", "TJ", "TK", "TL", "TM", "TN", "TO", "TP", "TQ", "TR", "TS", "TT", "TU", "TV", "TW", "TX", "TY", "TZ", "UA", "UB", "UC", "UD", "UE", "UF", "UG", "UH", "UI", "UJ", "UK", "UL", "UM", "UN", "UO", "UP", "UQ", "UR", "US", "UT", "UU", "UV", "UW", "UX", "UY", "UZ", "VA", "VB", "VC", "VD", "VE", "VF", "VG", "VH", "VI", "VJ", "VK", "VL", "VM", "VN", "VO", "VP", "VQ", "VR", "VS", "VT", "VU", "VV", "VW", "VX", "VY", "VZ", "WA", "WB", "WC", "WD", "WE", "WF", "WG", "WH", "WI", "WJ", "WK", "WL", "WM", "WN", "WO", "WP", "WQ", "WR", "WS", "WT", "WU", "WV", "WW", "WX", "WY", "WZ", "XA", "XB", "XC", "XD", "XE", "XF", "XG", "XH", "XI", "XJ", "XK", "XL", "XM", "XN", "XO", "XP", "XQ", "XR", "XS", "XT", "XU", "XV", "XW", "XX", "XY", "XZ", "YA", "YB", "YC", "YD", "YE", "YF", "YG", "YH", "YI", "YJ", "YK", "YL", "YM", "YN", "YO", "YP", "YQ", "YR", "YS", "YT", "YU", "YV", "YW", "YX", "YY", "YZ", "ZA", "ZB", "ZC", "ZD", "ZE", "ZF", "ZG", "ZH", "ZI", "ZJ", "ZK", "ZL", "ZM", "ZN", "ZO", "ZP", "ZQ", "ZR", "ZS", "ZT", "ZU", "ZV", "ZW", "ZX", "ZY", "ZZ" };

            int rowStartNumber = 3;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[alphabet[i].ToString() + rowStartNumber].Value = dr[i].ToString();
                }
                rowStartNumber++;
            }

            using (var range = worksheet.Cells[2, 1, 2, columnCount])
            {
                // Setting bold font
                range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                // Setting fill type solid
                range.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                // Setting background color dark blue
                range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.DarkBlue);
                // Setting font color
                range.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
            }

            // Setting AutoFit for all cells
            worksheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns(0);

            // Lets set the header text
            worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddHeader.CenteredText = ReportName;

            // Add the page number to the right of the footer + total number of pages
            worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.RightAlignedText = string.Format("Page {0} of {1}", ExcelHeaderFooter.PageNumber, ExcelHeaderFooter.NumberOfPages);

            // Add the sheet name to center of the footer
            worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.CenteredText = ExcelHeaderFooter.SheetName;

            // Add the filepath to the left of the footer
            worksheet.HeaderFooter.OddFooter.LeftAlignedText = ExcelHeaderFooter.FileName;

            // At the time of printing, when page page breaks, then the header will come in the next page by enabling this settings...
            worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatRows = worksheet.Cells["1:1"];
            worksheet.PrinterSettings.RepeatColumns = worksheet.Cells["A:" + alphabet[columnCount - 1].ToString()];
            //worksheet.PrinterSettings.PrintArea = worksheet.Cells["A,I"];
            worksheet.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.A4;
            worksheet.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
            worksheet.PrinterSettings.Scale = 100;

            // Change the sheet view to show it in page layout mode
            worksheet.View.PageLayoutView = false;

            // Setting some document properties
            package.Workbook.Properties.Title = ReportName;
            package.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Omer Mollamehmetoglu";
            package.Workbook.Properties.Comments = "This document created by ACME Co.Ltd.";

            // set some extended property values
            package.Workbook.Properties.Company = "ACME Co.Ltd.";

            // set some custom property values
            package.Workbook.Properties.SetCustomPropertyValue("Checked by", "Omer Mollamehmetoglu");
            package.Workbook.Properties.SetCustomPropertyValue("AssemblyName", "ACME Co.Ltd.");
            // save our new workbook and we are done!

            package.Save();
        }

        return newFile.FullName;
    }
```

Comment: i have download EPPlus ... but unreadable on my visual studios

Comment: i updated my comment with **screen shot** . Check out again please.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I just learned C# a few months ago 
and I also used stackoverflow for the first time, the name of EPPlus is : "epplus.4.5.3.1.nupkg" are there ? this file unreadable on my visual studios, so i dont know how to add to may refenreces. I'm really sorry sir and I hope you don't get bored answering my problems

Comment: No problem, if i can help you, i am happy for this. Floow this steps => Tools >> Nuget Package Manager >> Package Manager Console . It's opening a console panel. Visit  https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/ this address or paste **Install-Package EPPlus -Version 4.5.3.3**. Package Manager Console adding into to your references about of library on your solution. And than return my answer, set up your solution. If you are not fix your problem, write here, i will return you short time. good luck.